# Backpropagation in Keras model affects not all Layers?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

i have the following Model

```
inputs = Input(shape=(8))  # 8 groessen als eingabe
    x = Reshape((8, 1))(inputs)
    # generator
    x = Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))(x)
    x = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))(x)
    generated = LSTM(4, return_sequences=True, activation="sigmoid")(x)
    

    # rating
    x = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(generated)
    x = Bidirectional(LSTM(128))(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(16, activation="relu")(x)
    rating = Dense(8, activation="relu")(x)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[rating, generated])
    return model
```

i feed a sequence (8,) to the model, a generator should create a new sequence (8,4) out of this sequence that fulfill some conditions. There are a lot of outputs that could fulfil that condition, but my generator should just take one that it likes.

then i feed the generated sequence to the next layer, where i calculate the value (8,) of this output in order to be able to have gradients, when i apply my loss function

```
rating, generated = model(model_input, training=True)
calculated_rating = my_numeric_function(np.array(generated))
loss_1 = mse(model_input, rating) # the rating-loss
loss_2 = mse(calculated_rating , rating) # the loss between rating and generator
metric = mse(model_input, calculated_rating) # metric: difference between model input and real calculated 
tape.gradient(loss_1+loss_2, model.trainable_weights)
```

my loss1 and loss2 is decreasing, but the metric (calculated_rating - generated) stays exactly the same.

it seems that in backpropagation my loss function does not allow to change the weights of the generator layers.

what may be the reason that the metrics does not decrease ? (it stays around 51-52)

Comment: The answer to this question is not trivial. Have you tried varying the learning rate? Do you have enough training data? Have you tried looking into the data itself before forward step?

Comment: Hi Gabend, thanks for your comment. It was the learning rate! It was too low (Adam default), so the optimizer stuck into a wide local minimum. I set it to 0.1 for a few epoches, went down from 51 to 17, stopped and now i try to go lower. Thanks for your idea. That was a lucky outbreak.